# Angular Promise with $resource

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-resource

I have an angular promise which is generated by calling a custom api from $resource which returns an array of ids. I need to call another $resource api on each id and once all the details are loaded I want the original invocation to continue.

```
MyFactory.loadChildren(id).then(saveSuccess, saveFail);
MyFactory.loadChildren = function(id) {
      return MyResource.children({
        id: id
      }).$promise

        .then(function(response) {
          _.each(response, function(c) {
            MyResource.details({id:c.id}).$promise.then(function(child){
             //do something with the child



            },function(){

            })
          });
          return //all the children details;
        });
    };
```

I want the saveSuccess to be executed once all the child details are loaded. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $q.all. So your _.each will populate a promises array, and you'll call $q.all(thatArray). The function in the $q.all(thatArray) will then get an array of the results of all those calls and you can do a then() to do the final call. https://www.jonathanfielding.com/combining-promises-angular/